# Risk of getting MySQL database compromised with a client application

Tags: databases, mysql, websites, web-hosting

I want to make a client-side, Windows-based application that allows the user to register and it will store the registration details in an online MySQL server.

However when i googled ways to do this, I found that to establish such a MySQL connection I should provide an SQL user with write permissions and also provide that SQL user’s password (All these should be in my code).

This leads to a problem; if someone decompiled my application, they could get my SQL user and password, and they could see and do anything to my SQL database.

Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: I would never leave a database exposed to the internet, period.

Answer (score 5):

Yes and no.

First the no: As you have realized, if any data you put in an app that you send to a client can be extracted from it. You can take steps to make it harder to find the password (obfuscation, encryption, etc) but as a general rule of thumb, never put anything in the app that isn't supposed to be public.

So how do you protect your database password? Simple: don't store it in the app. Make a small web application that the app sends the registration details to, and then have the web application store things in the database. This way credentials never leave your control.

Comment: Basically like an API or middleman that transfer your credentials in a encrypted and secure way.